# Pass all params forward?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

Very simple question: how do you write a `link_to` that passes on all existing params to the target controller action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
link_to("My Link", params.merge({:controller => "my_controller", :action => "my_action"}))
```

Comment: Andrew, how would this work with the Rails 3 routing? i.e. what if the link_to is more like `link_to projects_url(...)`?

Comment: Just use `projects_url(params)`, or if you're using an object, `project_url(@project, params)`, or if you need more non-object designators, `projects_url(params.merge({...}))`.